# Stream encountered HTTP error: 403 Twitter API, but I have elevated access

Tags: python, tweepy

I have recently received elevated access to Twitter Developers. I have created a new project, and I have OAuth 1.0a turned on with permission to read and write, but when I ran code, I received: `Stream encountered HTTP error: 403`

```
import tweepy

from config import ACCESS_TOKEN as access_token
from config import ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET as access_token_secret
from config import API_KEY as api_key
from config import API_KEY_SECRET as api_key_secret

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_key_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

class Linstener(tweepy.Stream):
    tweets = []
    limit = 1

    def on_status(self, status):
        self.tweets.append(status)
        # print(status.user.screen_name + ": " + status.text)

        if len(self.tweets) == self.limit:
            self.disconnect()


stream_tweet = Linstener(api_key, api_key_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)

users = ['pawka322']
user_ids = []

for user in users:
    user_ids.append(api.get_user(screen_name=user).id)

stream_tweet.filter(follow=user_ids)
```

What I have done:

1. Created a new app and saved consumer key and consumer secret
2. Created a new Development project
3. Turned on OAuth 1.0a:

- Set app permission to Read and Write
- Filled User “Callback URI / Redirect URL” and “Website URL” with example org
  Generated access token and secret access token

My credentials work fine if I am getting Tweets from users timeline

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you created your app on or after 2022-04-29, you won't be able to access streaming with Twitter API v1.1:

> Additionally, beginning today, new client applications will not be able to gain access to v1.1 statuses/sample and v1.1 statuses/filter.

https://twittercommunity.com/t/deprecation-announcement-removing-compliance-messages-from-statuses-filter-and-retiring-statuses-sample-from-the-twitter-api-v1-1/170500

You'll have to use Twitter API v2 instead.
Tweepy's interface for streaming with Twitter API v2 is [`StreamingClient`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.8.0/streamingclient.html#tweepy.StreamingClient).

Comment: damn this hurts on so many levels